# ros libuvc_camera stopped working

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the rosrun on Nvidia Ubuntu 14.04 platform and i have USB Camera ( UVC Complaint ), i ran the following,

roscore
rosrun libuvc_camera camera_node

It worked fine, then i started installing the other components like kinect, stereo camera drivers ( some more components )

after that it stopped working,

root@tegra-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# rosrun --debug libuvc_camera camera_node

[rosrun] Looking in catkin libexec dirs: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libuvc_camera

[rosrun] Looking in rospack dir: /opt/ros/indigo/share/libuvc_camera

[rosrun] Searching for camera_node with permissions /111

[rosrun] Running  /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libuvc_camera/camera_node

[ INFO] [1474173238.408420389]: Opening camera with vendor=0x0, product=0x0, serial="", index=0
uvc_start_iso_streaming: Busy (-6)

before running this command, i have two video nodes video0 & video1 and i could able to see both videos using luvcview.

After i ran this command, i got only the video0 only ( also it seems that earlier video1 node becomes video0 )

Please share your inputs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243950/ros-libuvc_camera-stopped-working/) by [Hariharan Veerappan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28014/hariharan-veerappan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-18**:
Please use the *Preformatted text* button to format console copy/pastes. It's the on with `101010` on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have met this issue too.
And, I found that, if i uninstall "compressed-image-transport", then it works again.
But, I still don't know how to resolve it without uninstalling "compressed-image-transport".

---

Originally posted by [DanielLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28406/danielliu/) with karma: 16 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0